# Windows form closing & show method understanding

Tags: c#, winforms, formclosing

I need knowledge on below code execution.
On Form1 I have a button which calls another form Form2.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Form2 obj = new Form2();
obj.Show();
}
```

Since I have used show method, the execution will continue & it will get out of the event call. I am showing messagebox in Form2 FormClosing & FormClosed event but none of then were hit.

```
private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
MessageBox.Show("Form2 closed");
}

private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
MessageBox.Show("Form2 closing");
}
```

Any reason for this. Just out of curiosity I did this experiment & want to have knowledge on this.

Comment: Where are you calling the closing and closed methods and how are you subscribing to those events?

Comment: Did you hook your event handlers up to the events?

Comment: @Noobacode I am not calling the close event. The execution exits the function. Since i have created object of that form in the function, the life of the object will be till that function only. I was wondering after the form in shown, the execution exits but the object that showed that from will be destroyed coz of its scope. the form appears & in blink closes but no events are fired. You can try this on your machine & observe.

Comment: @VishalDeshmukh The code I've provided in my answer (both of the versions) work flawlessly.  I wouldn't be able to judge what you did wrong if you say that you've subscribed to those events properly, unless you provide more code.  The little bits you've provided do not paint the entire picture.

Answer (score 1):

Both events should be triggered but probably you didn't attach the event handlers correctly.Write this code inside of your  `Form_Load` event of `Form2` and try again:

```
this.Form1_FormClosed += Form2_FormClosed;
this.Form1_FormClosing += Form2_FormClosing;
```

Comment: Just try to create such scenario on your machine & check. You will subscribe to events properly but they are not hit.

Comment: Please post code here of how did you call form 2 on button click

Answer (score 1):

Since `obj` was not declared as global, it will be out of scope after the event handler terminates. Try making the instance global, i.e. not in a method, and only calling the `Show` method in the event handler. That should do the trick.

Comment: Event handlers are attached properly. Since form appears & then dissapears since the object access level is ended, the form is not closed. if it was closed the form2 clsed event will be called which did not. i have curiosity to know why so???

Answer (score 1):

So, it sounds like you were not subscribing to your events:

Here's how your code should look:

**Form1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 obj = new Form2();
        obj.Show();
    }
}
```

**Form2**

```
partial class Form2
{
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
        this.Name = "Form2";
        this.Text = "Form2";
        this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.Form2_FormClosing);
        this.FormClosed += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventHandler(this.Form2_FormClosed);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Form2 closed.");
    }

    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Form2 closing.");
    }
}
```

**It is also possible to keep it all inside Form1 (as far as subscription):**

**Form1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 obj = new Form2();
        obj.Show();
        obj.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(Form2_FormClosing);
        obj.FormClosed += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventHandler(Form2_FormClosed);
    }

    private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Form2 closed.");
    }

    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Form2 closing.");
    }
}
```

The two versions of code I've provided have been tested and work just fine.  However, you've only shown us three methods, and we have no idea what else you're doing that may cause your problems.  It's a good idea to learn how to debug.  For example, set a brake point prior to the code that doesn't execute, even under perceived "proper" conditions.  You can then step through the code and see where an error occurs.  You'll be surprised how many bugs you'll catch this way.

Comment: Event handlers are attached properly. Since form appears & then dissapears since the object access level is ended, the form is not closed. if it was closed the form2 clsed event will be called which did not. i have curiosity to know why so???

Comment: @VishalDeshmukh Well, closing and opening has nothing to do with your subscription to those events.  The window can close and open just fine, but if you didn't subscribe to those events, you're not going to fire off code based on those events.

Comment: this.FormClosed += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventHandler(this.Form2_FormClosed);
            this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.Form2_FormClosing);

Comment: FYI i have attached events.

Comment: @VishalDeshmukh Where did you do that at?  You should show us all of your code.  It's hard to judge from the bit you're provided.

Comment: Yes the code you did is perfect. Once you click on button in Form1 the Form2 shows up. Now close Form1. The Form1 closes and also Form2 closes but the Form2 events are not hit. Observe this.

Comment: @VishalDeshmukh That is not something you mentioned earlier or even in your original post.  Try to be more specific in the future.

Comment: OK..ill make sure about that..but as you understood it...any comments on why so ???.

Comment: @VishalDeshmukh I don't have exact knowledge on it, but my guess is that it's due to the fact that when your main window (which is the parent of its child) shuts down, any close calls only pertain to it, unless you specifically trigger them in the closing events of the parent window.  So, you may put something like `if (childForm != null) { // do something }` into the closing handler of the parent window.  You can put a prompt asking the user if they want to shut down the application and depending on their answer, you may cancel the closing routine. I spend more time working with WPF.

Answer (score 1):

> the execution exits but the object that showed that from will be destroyed coz of its scope.

Ah, no the form wont die, it will stay alive and use the event loop of application's main form  which contains `button1`.

> form appears & in blink closes

This maybe due to some other reason. You maybe hiding the form, or you have some other code in Form2 `Load` event. The form may be getting hidden and not closed.